# What XSD Version used in WSO2 ESB 4.8.1

Tags: xsd, wso2, schema, wso2-esb

What XSD Version used in WSO2 Esb 4.8.1 and is it possible to use XSD Schema 1.1 in WSO2ESB 4.8.1

Thanks